# Need help giving Plex media server permission to access external NTFS drive from raspberry pi 3

Tags: permissions, media-server, fstab

I am running the Plex media server on my raspberry pi 3 (Raspbian Jessie).  My media is mounted on the RPI3 from an external NTFS drive.  I'm accessing my Plex media server from my laptop remotely.  When I try and add media into my Plex library it sees the mounted NTFS drive but won't add the media into the library.  Says it can't find any.

This is the fstab on my RPI3..

```
UUID=58045633045613FA /media/external ntfs-3g uid=deanresin,gid=deanresin,fmask=117,dmask=017,permissions,nosuid,noexec,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,x-gvfs-name=external 0 0
```

I tried to change Plex user to `deanresin` in `/etc/default/plexmediaserver.prev` in the line...

```
PLEX_MEDIA_SERVER_USER=deanresin
```

then I restarted the server with `sudo service plexmediaserver restart`

On my laptop I go to `https://app.plex.tv/desktop#` and try and add files into my library by browsing to `media/external`.  I see the sub-directories but they are faded and I can't select them which to me seems to be a permission issue.

Please help.  I have Kodi running on my RPI3 and it can access my files no problem.  Plex is giving me headaches.

Comment: What operating system you are running?

Comment: Raspbian Jessie